# Creating a Modal Dialog or Window in Cocoa Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I need to create an modal dialog, which is to loaded from a nib file and should be displayed on a button click in the main window.

I can create a custom window in a nib file and load the custom dialog on button click, but it's not a modal dialog. I can switch back to the main window.

`MyWindowController` is the `NSWindowController` subclass.
I used the code below to display my window in response to the button event:

```
MyWindowController *pController = [[MyWindowController alloc] 
                                   initWithWindowNibName:@"nibfilename"];
[MyWindowController showWindow:self];
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several ways to do this — and in fact two different kinds of modal dialog in OS X: application-modal and window-modal. Using the wrong one will annoy people. One is a sheet, which is attached to the window that it affects (save dialogs are an example of this). The other is application-modal, which blocks the whole application (open dialogs work this way, since they don't apply to any window that exists yet). Apple's [sheet documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html) should help get you oriented.

Answer (score 11):

Thank you...

(Example).
Create a nib with name "About"

```
if(pAbtCtrl == nil)
        pAbtCtrl = [[AboutWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"About"];

pAbtWindow = [pAbtCtrl window];

[NSApp runModalForWindow: pAbtWindow];

[NSApp endSheet: pAbtWindow];

[pAbtWindow orderOut: self];
```

Comment: pAbtWindow ?? can you please explain.