# NSApplication endSheet: has no effect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsapplication

Ok, this is really stumping me:

I create a modal sheet on a window as

```
-(IBAction) login: (id) sender {
[NSApp beginSheet:loginWindow 
   modalForWindow:window 
    modalDelegate:nil 
   didEndSelector:nil 
      contextInfo:nil];
}
```

and try to remove it with

```
-(IBAction) loginWindowCancelPressed:   (id) sender {
debugLog(@"cancel");
[NSApp endSheet:loginWindow];
}
```

but it remains.

I've checked all of the obvious things like IB connections and ensuring that window and loginWindow are present and in the normal state.

So, the question is: Am I missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to set up a delegate for the sheet. The delegate should implement a method with a signature like the following:

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

(You can use a different name if you like, but it should accept the same parameters.)

You can do whatever you need to do in that method, but ultimately it should end with:

```
[sheet orderOut:self];
```

which will dismiss the sheet.

Comment: You don't actually need a delegate (it's optional). The only thing missing is the call to orderOut:

Comment: I have setup a delegate and selector. The sheet is controlled by a window controller. Calling endSheet: has no effect (the delegate is NEVER notified). Calling stopModal works, but it is wrong and causes problems when displaying further sheets. WTF? Cocoa for the desktop really sucks big time. 90% of the time spent dealing with these idiosyncracies...

Comment: calling orderOut on an instance of NSWindow closes the window, not the sheet.

Comment: @auco: A sheet is an instance of `NSWindow`.

Answer (score 5):

See: [Creating a Modal Dialog or Window in Cocoa Objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902618/creating-a-modal-dialog-or-window-in-cocoa-objective-c)

A delegate is not required. The following works for me to dismiss and allows calling it back later:

```
[NSApp endSheet: loginWindow];
[loginWindow orderOut:self];
```

Comment: For pure simplicity, this is a useful solution. Works with the new storyboard system for OSX as well.